# Generate and Returning Dynamic Class Runtime in Java

Tags: java, methods, dynamic, runtime, generator

I actually have these kind of repeatable statements such as :

```
public ArrayList<User> getAllUser() {

    ArrayList<User> allData = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        Connection conn = DBConnector.connect();

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM data_user";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            User singleData = new User();
            singleData.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            singleData.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            singleData.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            singleData.setIdDivision(rs.getInt("id_division"));
            singleData.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            allData.add(singleData);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    return allData;
}
```

As all we can see that code clearly. Inside that **while-loop** my case begin.

Let me explain it a little bit here. In every *instance* of that *User* object class it's matched to the column name (in mysql database column). And that would happen for other Variable Instance of other Object classes.

But I wonder if i could do it automatically. So the ***ResultSet process of*** :

1. Getting String
2. Getting Int
3. Getting other type

Would be automatically as well. **Including, the Setter method from that User Object that ended up into an arrayList**. So I wonder if there's some kind of functions/library that runs like these code:

```
ResultBuilder rb = new ResultBuilder();
rb.setArrayContainer(allData);
rb.setResultSet(rs);
rb.setObjectClassData(User.class);
rb.execute();
allData = rb.getArrayContainerBack();
```

**Would it be possible for not :**

1. Doing manual User/Other Object calling Set(s) method
2. Doing manual Getting Value from Method to Column Name (resultset)

Anyone could give me a clue in **Java Flavour**?

Comment: Voting to close since there are already questions that covers JDBC boilerplate.

Comment: aaaha... you're right...! Apache common DBUtils is quite good for this case! :D I just found the matching points from these paragraph : "a few methods also receive a ResultSetHandler implementation – which is responsible for transforming ResultSet instances into the objects our application expects." thank u  everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about an ORM(Object Relational Mapping).
Most popular for java is Hibernate: http://hibernate.org/